# For Loops List Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Do you know any tips for "For Loops List".

Comment: Btw: asking on Stackoverflow is not considered research but if you need a resource to learn about python control flow: there you go [for-loops](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)

Comment: Yes, doing your own research will probably help you as a programmer.

Comment: There's no shortage of Python tutorials, starting with the official one...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
numbers = ['1', 2, 34, '898']
for number in numbers:
     print(number)
```